# How to remove repeated items of a list and copy the list into another list

Tags: java

I have a list of items that need to remove their repeated ones and then copy the list into another list. The problem is that I cant copy the list into the other list.

**Code**

```
    .....
    private List mylist = new ArrayList();
    .....

    LinkedHashSet hs = new LinkedHashSet();
    hs.addAll(mylist);
    mylist.clear();
    mylist.addAll(hs); 

    MyClass.getItems().clear();
    MyClass.setItems(mylist);
```

**MyClass.java**

```
  .....
   private List Items = new ArrayList();

   public void setItems(List myItems) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < myItems.size(); i++) {    <<This loop shows the items
            System.out.println(myItems.get(i));
        }
        this.Items.clear();
        this.Items.addAll(myItems);
        for (int i = 0; i < Items.size(); i++) {  << this loop does not show anything
           System.out.println(Items.get(i));
        }
    }
```

**Desired result**

```
mylist  >> a,b,c,a,d,c
change to a,b,c,d
then copy to items
items >> a,b,c,d
```

Comment: To fix the first problem, just use a `LinkedHashSet` instead of a `HashSet`.

Comment: what do you mean by you cant copy one list into another?

Comment: As shown in the code when I send the list as a parameter of setItems, the for loop in the setItems does not show the items, seems the items are not sent to the setItems function for some reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html). This will preserve the insertion order and insure no duplicates.

for problem number two are you adding anyting to the list. the code you have works

```
List<Integer> mylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    mylist.add(3);
    mylist.add(3);


    HashSet hs = new HashSet();
    hs.addAll(mylist);
    mylist.clear();
    mylist.addAll(hs); 

    System.out.println(mylist.size()); //prints 1
    System.out.println(hs.size());// prints 1
```

**RESPONSE to edited question:**

They both seem to print out the list fine

```
public class Tmp {  

private List<Integer> Items = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void setItems(List<Integer> myItems) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < myItems.size(); i++) {    //<<This loop shows the items
        System.out.println(myItems.get(i));
    }
    this.Items.clear();
    this.Items.addAll(myItems);
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < Items.size(); i++) {  //<< this loop also shows the item
        System.out.println(Items.get(i));
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tmp t = new Tmp();
    List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    myList.add(3);
    myList.add(4);

    t.setItems(myList);


}
```

}

Are both these pieces of code in the same class and both list variables pointing to the same arrayList instance. if so calling clear on one clears out both lists (since both variables are pointing to the same list)

Comment: how to solvve the second problem?

Comment: you want to copy the set into an already created list? what about the add all function http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)

Comment: you used it with the hashset which does not maintain the order like a linked hashlist. When you call the add ALL on the list it will call the collection you are passing in iterator to iterate over the collection adding each object to the list

Comment: setItems function is in another class, when I pass the mylist to functions it gets emptied.

Comment: mylist declaration is as private List mylist = new ArrayList(); I do not know why it is emptied when passed to the dunctions of myClass.

Comment: is there another thread that is editing the list? I have used the sample code you gave and i am not able to replicate the error. Is there anymore information you can provide

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30370/discussion-between-jack-ramzi-and-user2242863)